# Upload file and text with Method POST on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, post, form-data

I'm trying to send a JSON to the web service with a file and some text, but the server answers as invalid.
I have been looking through this for 3 days and can't get what's wrong, so I ask you for help.

This is the web form to talk to the web service:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Nova Dica Form</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <form action="http://serveraddress.com/newtip" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="textoDica" value="Ola teste dica">
    <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="recomendou" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="idTags" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="idMarcas" value="1">    
    <input type="hidden" name="idLocais" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="idCategorias" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="idImpressoes" value="">
    <input name="foto1" type="file">
    <input name="foto2" type="file">
    <input name="foto3" type="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what the php developer sent me:

```
POST /newtip
Host: serveraddress.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Representation:

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textoDica"

texto-dica
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto1"
Content-Type: image/jpeg, image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

foto1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto2"
Content-Type: image/jpeg, image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

foto2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto3"
Content-Type: image/jpeg, image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

foto3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recomendou";

recomendou
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idUsuario";

id-usuario
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idTags";

id-tag
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idMarcas";

id-marca
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idLocais";

id-local
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idCategorias";

id-categoria
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idImpressoes";

id-Impressao

Response
Content-Type: application/json
Representation:
{ "fotoDica" : "http://s3.amazonaws.com/cooltips/dicas/f23f89as.jpg",
  "horarioDica" : 1372711615696,
  "idDica" : 21,
  "recomendado" : 1,
  "textoDica" : "TesteDica1"
}
```

So, based on that, I did this in my code (with some content I found here at stackoverflow:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://serveraddress.com/newtip"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// Header
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
// Body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// Dica/Tip
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textoDica\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Teste de texto blablabla." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Usuario
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idUsuario\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"72" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Recomendou
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"recomendou\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"true" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Tags
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idTags\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"aaaaaa;bbbbbb;cccccc" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Marca
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idMarcas\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"3" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Local
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idLocais\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"4" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Categorias
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idCategorias\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Impressões
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"idImpressoes\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"bom;alegre" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Fotos / Image Files
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foto1\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: file/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_fotoArray[0], 0.40);
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
// Final Boundary
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Set the body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

I always get this answer from the server:

```
{"idDica":0,"fotoDica":null,"horarioDica":null,"textoDica":null,"recomendado":0}
```

But the right one should be something like this:

```
{"idDica":91,"fotoDica":"http://serveraddress.com/tips/91/6nyIZA8MPJ.png","horarioDica":1372960438226,"textoDica":"Hello","recomendado":1}
```

Can anyone have a clue on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the web service code (out of my knowledge):

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DicaRest uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("foto1") InputStream uploadedInputStream1,
    @FormDataParam("foto1") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail1,
    @FormDataParam("foto2") InputStream uploadedInputStream2,
    @FormDataParam("foto2") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail2,
    @FormDataParam("foto3") InputStream uploadedInputStream3,
    @FormDataParam("foto3") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail3,
    @FormDataParam("textoDica") String textoDica,
    @FormDataParam("idUsuario") long idUsuario,
    @FormDataParam("recomendou") boolean recomendou,
    @FormDataParam("idTags") String idTags,
    @FormDataParam("idMarcas") String idMarcas,
    @FormDataParam("idLocais") String idLocais,
    @FormDataParam("idCategorias") String idCategorias,
    @FormDataParam("idImpressoes") String idImpressoes)
{
    if(idTags == null)
        idTags = "";
    if(idMarcas == null)
        idMarcas = "";
    if(idLocais == null)
        idLocais = "";
    if(idCategorias == null)
        idCategorias = "";
    if(idImpressoes == null)
        idImpressoes = "";
    EntityManager em = EntityFactory.getEntityManager("RestCTPU");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    DicaRest dicaRest = new DicaRest();
    Upload upload = new Upload();
    List<File> pathfoto = new ArrayList<File>();
    Dica novaDica = new Dica();
    int i = 0;

    try {
        novaDica.setTextoDica(textoDica);
        novaDica.setIdUsuario(new Usuario(idUsuario));
        novaDica.setRecomendado(recomendou);
        novaDica.setDataCadastro(new Date());
        novaDica.setEstadoHabilitado(true);
        novaDica = em.merge(novaDica);

        //LINUX AMI
        String pathLocal = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/uploadtemp/"+novaDica.getIdDica() + "/";

        //WINDOWS
        //String pathLocal = "C:/teste/"+"dicas/"+novaDica.getIdDica() + "/";
        String pathAlvo = "dicas/"+novaDica.getIdDica() + "/";
        (new File(pathLocal)).mkdirs();
        if (fileDetail1.getFileName().length() > 0) {
            pathfoto.add( new File(pathLocal+Utilidades.getRandomPass(10)+fileDetail1.getFileName().substring(fileDetail1.getFileName().lastIndexOf("."))));
            saveToFile(uploadedInputStream1, pathfoto.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
            i++;
        }
        if (fileDetail2.getFileName().length() > 0) {
            pathfoto.add( new File(pathLocal +Utilidades.getRandomPass(10)+fileDetail1.getFileName().substring(fileDetail1.getFileName().lastIndexOf("."))));
            saveToFile(uploadedInputStream2, pathfoto.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
            i++;
        }
        if (fileDetail3.getFileName().length() > 0) {
            pathfoto.add( new File(pathLocal+Utilidades.getRandomPass(10)+fileDetail1.getFileName().substring(fileDetail1.getFileName().lastIndexOf("."))));
            saveToFile(uploadedInputStream3, pathfoto.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
            i++;
        }

        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
        if(idTags.length() > 0) {
            String[] tgs = idTags.split(";");
            for(String tag : tgs) {
                Tag nTag = new Tag(Long.valueOf(tag));
                tags.add(nTag);
            }
        }
        novaDica.setTagList(tags);
        List<Alvo> alvos = new ArrayList<Alvo>();
        if(idMarcas.length() > 0) {
                String[] marcas = idMarcas.split(";");
                for(String marca : marcas) {
                    Alvo nAlvo = new Alvo(Long.valueOf(marca));
                    alvos.add(nAlvo);
                }
        }
        if(idLocais.length() > 0) {
            String[] locais = idLocais.split(";");
            for(String local : locais) {
                Alvo nAlvo = new Alvo(Long.valueOf(local));
                alvos.add(nAlvo);
            }
        }
        novaDica.setAlvoList(alvos);
        List<CategoriaImpressao> categoriaImpressaoList = new ArrayList<CategoriaImpressao>();
        if(idCategorias.length() > 0) {
            String[] categorias = idCategorias.split(";");
            for(String categoria : categorias) {
                CategoriaImpressao nCat = new CategoriaImpressao(Long.valueOf(categoria));
                categoriaImpressaoList.add(nCat);
            }
        }
        if(idImpressoes.length() > 0) {
            String[] impressoes = idImpressoes.split(";");
            for(String impressao : impressoes) {
                CategoriaImpressao nImpress = new CategoriaImpressao(Long.valueOf(impressao));
                categoriaImpressaoList.add(nImpress);
            }
        }
        novaDica.setCategoriaImpressaoList(categoriaImpressaoList);
        //String uploadedFileLocation = fileDetail1.getFileName();
        // save it
        List<Foto> fts = new ArrayList<Foto>();
        for(String foto : upload.doUpload(pathfoto, pathAlvo)) {
            Foto ft = new Foto();
            ft.setUrlFoto(foto);
            ft.setIdDica(novaDica);
            ft.setDataCadastro(new Date());
            ft.setEstadoHabilitado(true);
            fts.add(ft);
        }
        novaDica.setFotoList(fts);
        em.persist(novaDica);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        try {
            deleteDir(new File(pathLocal));
        } catch (Exception e){}
        dicaRest.setFotoDica(fts.get(0).getUrlFoto());
        dicaRest.setHorarioDica(new Date());
        dicaRest.setIdDica(novaDica.getIdDica());
        dicaRest.setRecomendado(recomendou);
        dicaRest.setTextoDica(textoDica);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
        em.getEntityManagerFactory().close();
    }

    return dicaRest; 
}
```

Comment: Try generating your POST data in a NSString and convert it to NSData at the end.

`NSString *args = @"chave1=valor1&chave2=valor2"`

Comment: @sp4rkbr By POST data you mean the `NSMutableURLRequest`?

Comment: And if I pass these values as you said, how can I send the image?

Comment: Ooops I didn't notice you were sending an image. In this case you can consider using base64 and sending it as an string too.

Comment: @sp4rkbr That's certainly an option, but shouldn't be necessary (and makes the upload significantly larger/slower). And it's certainly not compatible with the existing interface that OP is trying to integrate.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your replies. I did what you said (match the values and add the two other files) and I got the same result.
Do you think it's better if I can get the php code to see what's going on in server side?

Comment: @Rob I've updated the question with the web service code. Thank you!

Comment: You can use be this library that will work on any kind of web service: github.com/mineshpurohit/ServiceCallingUtility

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying specifying the upload filename, too, e.g.:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fieldName, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

You also use a `Content-Type` of `file/jpeg`, but the spec from the developer says it should be `image/jpeg` or `image/png`. So you might want to use:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If neither of those do it, I notice that your values don't exactly match the HTML example, exactly, and given that we don't know what the validation rules are, I'd suggest you use precisely the same values (e.g. `idTags` is `2` in the HTML, but `aaaaaa;bbbbbb;cccccc` in your Objective-C). But we have no way of knowing what validation the PHP is performing, so eliminate the possibility that you're just not passing some simple validation rule. Make sure you're confident the problem is the forming of the request, and not the data you're passing in the request.

Hopefully your PHP developer can tell you precisely what validation is taking place.

---

Looking at your sample server source code, I am not familiar enough with this server code to diagnose it, but a couple of thoughts:

1. It seems like the references that grab the extension of `fileDetail1` when working with `fileDetail2` and `fileDetail3` seems like it can't be right (what if they were different types?!?). Given that you're passing only one, that's unlikely to be the source of the problem, but it doesn't seem right.
2. It would suggest, though, that consistent with my earlier observation about supplying a filename, it's important to do so, and probably one with a `jpg` extension. I would encourage you to include a filename (even if it's just `"test.jpg"`).
3. This code makes me wonder what happens when your request doesn't pass any `foto2` or `foto3`. Hopefully it handles that gracefully, not throwing any exception, but I can't say.
4. I may be misreading this, but it looks like your `idTags` must be numbers separated by semicolons, not `aaaaaa;bbbbbb;cccccc`. See the references to `Long`.
5. It looks like the same is true with `idImpressoes`, that it should be numbers separate by semicolons, not `bom;alegre`.

It strikes me that point 4 and point 5 are the most immediate candidate issues. I'd make both of those numbers and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it made no change in the result.
I can add that the filename will be generate automatically on the server side.

Comment: I'll take the code and update my question as soon as I get it. Thanks

Comment: 1. It was really wrong and is already corrected, but as you said, I'm sending only one image and it has no effect on the result;
2. I have included the filename in `@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foto1\"; filename=\"image1.jpg\"\r\n"` but no changes on the result;
3. I tried to send just one image, two and three together, but nothing changes;
4. You're right. I changed the values and the result still null;
5. Same as 4 here.
I'm really stuck on this issue. If you have any thoughts about this, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: @Tchelow That's all good progress, but it's too bad it doesn't solve it. I notice that the server code does a `System.out.println(e);` if it catches an exception. Have you looked at the server logs and see what it says?

Comment: I have no access to it, but I can ask for those logs... As soon as I get it, I come back with you. Thanks.