# multipart form data not invoking the web service API

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a multipart form data from an iOS client. The data is a multipart data and I am sure about it.

The server is based on JAX-RS (Jersery). If I am using the below code

```
@POST
@Path("/customerdetail")
@Consumes({"multipart/form-data"})
public String postCustomerDetails(InputStream message){ 

StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bufferedReader; try { bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(message, "UTF-8")); 
String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
while(line != null){ inputStringBuilder.append(line);
inputStringBuilder.append('\n'); 
line = bufferedReader.readLine(); }
System.out.println(inputStringBuilder.toString()); 

}
```

I am getting the multipart form data as an input stream. But I am stuck as how should I proceed further to extract data from the input string apart from implementing tiresome string manipulations.

If I use the below code

```
@POST
@Path("/customerdetail")
@Consumes({"multipart/form-data"})
public String postCustomerDetails(FormDataMultiPart  formParams) {

}
```

the postCustomerDetails method is not getting invoked at all.

Any input on how to parse the multipart data will be much helpful. Am I using the right approach. Jersey experts pls. help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your first approach, you didn't annotate which 'part' you want from the multipart request, hence your `InputStream message` returns all original multipart request body.

What you need to do, is to specify which form name contains your file upload.

For instance, if your client side has `<input type="file" name="myfile">`

```
public String postCustomerDetails(@FormDataParam("myfile") InputStream message){...}
```

In this way, `message` only contains the content of your uploaded file, so you don't have to parse the whole request body to dig it out.

Maybe you are not using html form in you client app, but built some multipart request manually, you still need to know what are the names in the form.

In your current approach, just print out the whole request body, it would be something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608

--Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hello"

hello
--Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><jaxbBean><value>xml</value></jaxbBean>
--Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"value":"json"}
--Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608--
```

The `name="hello"` is what you are after. Then you can get the 3 parts like this:

```
public String postCustomerDetails(
  @FormDataParam("hello") InputStream helloInput,  // the file input for "hello"
  @FormDataParam("hello") FormDataContentDisposition helloDetail, // optional, for getting file name and size, etc
  @FormDataParam("xml") InputStream xmlInput,
  @FormDataParam("xml") FormDataContentDisposition xmlDetail,
  @FormDataParam("json") InputStream jsonInput,
  @FormDataParam("json") FormDataContentDisposition jsonDetail
){...}
```

And for your second approach with `FormDataMultiPart`, I never use that low level api, but I just tested and it works. I have no idea why it is not triggered for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is no file involved in my input stream. All the data are in string format. Given this scenario, Is the below approach correct   public String postCustomerDetails(
  @FormDataParam("name1") InputStream helloInput,@FormDataParam("name2") InputStream helloInput,@FormDataParam("name3") InputStream helloInput){..}. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Yes, but you can not name all of them after helloInput :), vary your variable name.

Comment: @huocp- Thanks. I tried this. Still not working. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: any exception? what's reading out of @FormDataParam("name1") InputStream helloInput?

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475985/upload-file-and-text-with-method-post-on-ios

Comment: But my issue here is the content is not hitting the server. I am also using the same server code styling (coincidentally).

Comment: I see, just to double confirm, did you turn on MultiPartFeature in your `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` sub-class? (like `classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);`)